# Retrieve certain posts by their number?

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts

How can I call certain posts by their number to place them as featured posts in specific places of my template ?
I've read about sticky posts , But I have about 3 places to place my featured posts and I guess I need a loop to get posts by their number I defined.

Any HELP ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   

// The Query    
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=7' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I've tried the same code before but the problem is: it shows only one post, and whenever I separate multiple IDs by comma, Only the first one appears. Any suggestions ? or should I only repeat the loop according no. of posts I want ??

Comment: Use `new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) )`