# Wordpress problem while retrieving certain posts by their number?

Tags: wordpress, loops, post

I asked a question before about the same question here :
[Retrieve certain posts by their number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924489/retrive-certain-posts-by-their-number)

every thing was going fine and I called 4 posts, but the problem appeared suddenly and only 3 are appearing now !

here is the code I use

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => array( 264, 137, 145 , 88 ) ) ); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

">

what is wrong with my code ??
I'm sure these post numbers are correct and I tried many many of them and all have the same effect

Comment: Do you have Wordpress set up to display only 3 posts per page?

Comment: wow, I didn't even think of that ! and yes, the default setting for "Blog pages show at most" was only 3 , I didn't notice that before.
Many thanks Richard.BTW, Is there a way to override that default number? I already sat it to 10 but in case I need to do that some where else. And also why don't you post your comment as answer to mark it as true one ? Thanks again for your kind efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a different number of posts from the 'Blog pages show at most' setting just add a `posts_per_page` parameter to your query. In the case where you are also using `post__in` you probably want to set this to `-1` so all the posts are returned.

```
new WP_Query(array(
  'post__in' => array(264, 137, 145 , 88),
  'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```